# Conditional nginx logging if $http_x_forwarded_for exists?

Tags: nginx, logging

I have a web server that sits behind a load balancer, and I am trying to get the logs to have the first value be either `$http_x_forwarded_for` (if it exists) or `$remote_addr` if `$http_x_forwarded_for`is empty (because sometimes I hit the machine directly, sometimes I am forwarded from the load balancer).

I have tried the following without success:

```
set $realip $http_x_forwarded_for;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~ "") {
    set $realip $remote_addr;
    }
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $realip;
```

as well as

```
set $realip $remote_addr;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~ "^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)") {
    set $realip $1;
    }
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $realip;
```

(both of which only log the correct IP if I am hitting the box directly, all load balance hits show the ip of the load balancer instead of the forwarded IP)

I have also tried

```
map $http_x_forwarded_for $forwardexists {
        ~*^(?![\s\S]) $http_x_real_ip; ## also tried ~"" and just "" to match empty
        default $http_x_forwarded_for;
        }


    log_format forwardedIP '$forwardexists $remote_user [$time_local] '
                        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent"' ;
```

and then using `forwardedIP` as my log format, but that will only show forwarded IPs and leaves all other requests completely blank.

Is there some way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UGH finally figured it out, I needed to use:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_for $forwardexists {
        "" $remote_addr;
        default $http_x_forwarded_for;
        }
```